# ostream operator<< not working properly

Tags: c++, arrays, printing, hashtable, ostream

ostream issues
My ostream operator << seems not to be working or something else

Comment: umm, i would imagine (int)key[i]  can give you garbage data because of size mismatch...

Comment: my size is 512, and the size that goes in to the getHash is 512. What would you suggest? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a logic error in the function `Customer::getHash`. That may not solve your problem but it should be fixed anyway.

```
int Customer::getHash(int hash)
{
    string key = getLastname();
    cout<<"key: "<<key<<endl;
    // getFirstname();
    //  getID();
    int i = 0;
    // int j = 0;
    // int k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < key.length(); i++)
    {
        i += (int)key[i]; // Problem.
                          // At this time, i may be greater than key.length().
    }
   // getFirstname();
   // getID();
   return  i = i % hash;

}
```

You can fix it by using a different variable to keep the temporary hash value.

```
int Customer::getHash(int hash)
{
    string key = getLastname();
    cout<<"key: "<<key<<endl;
    int tempHash = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < key.length(); i++)
    {
        tempHash += (int)key[i];
    }
   return  tempHash % hash;    
}
```

**Update**

In your posted code, you have commented out the return statement in the function

```
istream &operator >> (istream &in, Customer &obj)
```

As a side effect, the behavior of

```
 while (inputFile >> newCustomer)
```

is undefined.

Uncomment the line

```
//return in;
```

in the function. That will fix another error. Hopefully that's the last one.

**Update 2**

You are reading too much information in the `while` loop.

```
 // This line reads all the information of one customer
 while (inputFile >> newCustomer)
 {
    //inputFile >> newCustomer;
    string lastname;

    // PROBLEM
    // Now you are reading data corresponding to the next customer.

    getline (inputFile, lastname, ' ');
    while (inputFile.peek() == ' ')
       inputFile.get();

    string firstname;
    getline (inputFile, firstname, ' ');
    while (inputFile.peek() == ' ')
       inputFile.get();

    string id;
    getline (inputFile, id);

    buildCustomerList(cHeadPtr, cTailPtr, lastname, firstname, id);
    customer.insert(newCustomer);
    //cout<<lastname<<endl;
    //cout<<firstname<<endl;
    //cout<<id<<endl;
 }
```

Change it to:

```
 while (inputFile >> newCustomer)
 {
    string lastname = newCustomer.getLastname();
    string firstname = newCustomer.getFirstname();
    string id = newCustomer.getID();

    buildCustomerList(cHeadPtr, cTailPtr, lastname, firstname, id);
    customer.insert(newCustomer);
 }
```

Comment: Ohh I see my mistake. Thanks! Does my for loop work correctly? It seems to me that there is something very simple, here but I can't catch it!! Thanks

Comment: @kris, the `for` loop looks OK to me.

Comment: @R Sahu, I posted my full program. I am thinking maybe when I am reading the file and setting my data, something goes wrong?

Comment: Any help would be really appreciated, I litterly spent about 3 full days on this problem and I think I am almost done

Comment: @R Sahu, thanks for the help. That did not fix my problem, but that was part of it. Thanks! I guess my setting and inserting functions are getting screwed since only one record is getting printed instead of 512

Comment: @R Sahu!!! This solved my problem!!! Wow thanks so much!! :) Do you mind explaining me why my old code didn't read? THANKS

Comment: @kris, you were reading too much information in the `while` loop. While trying to process information about one customer, you were reading the data corresponding to the next customer.